# Cut strips on subframes (soft or hard) video sequence editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am trying to sync a audio file with a video file.
Thee video has its own audio but the quality is poor, so I recorded the audio footage with a Dictaphone to replace the video clip's audio.

I have enabled "subframes" in "playback" menu.
so the playhead can scrub along the subframes but when I attempt to use the knife tool to make a cut, it only makes cuts on the frames and not on the playhead (in subframe)

I've been searching for quite a wile to find an answer to this with no luck.
any freed back would be appreciated.

Maybe this is a bug? When I try to make the cut the menu that pops up allowed me to type in the exact point I want to cut but once selected it rounds it down/up to the nearest frame.

The same happens when I try to put a marker along the time line.

Comment: Cutting on subframes is not implemented in the VSE, afaik.